# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::row_array()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hey i am novice in CI so please forgive! I am trying to join 2 tables in codeigniter and i am getting here these error in my code

> Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::row_array() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Hostel\application\models\payfees.php on line 16.

My Code for the method is here like these

```
public function payu($id,$month){
        $where = "where generatebills.student_id='".$id."' and generatebills.month='".$month."'";
                   $query =  $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('generatebills')
                    ->join('student','student.student_id=generatebills.student_id')
                    ->where($where);
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Comment: don't forget `->get()` method

Comment: @Ghost sorry my bad i be better more carefull next time and also now i am getting an sql syntax error which is like these You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'generatebills.student_id='' and generatebills.month=''' at line 4.But thanks any way man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the missing `->get()` method. Plus, remove the `WHERE` in the string:

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
```

> http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

I'd suggest use an array instead:

```
public function payu($id,$month)
{
    // $where = "generatebills.student_id='".$id."' and generatebills.month='".$month."'";
    $where = array(
        'generatebills.student_id' => $id,
        'generatebills.month' => $month,
    );

    $query =  $this->db->select('generatebills.*')
        ->from('generatebills')
        ->join('student','student.student_id = generatebills.student_id')
        ->where($where);

    return $query->get()->row_array();
               //  ^
}
```